# One-sample versions of the signed rank and rank sum tests?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I wonder if there are applications of the signed rank and rank sum tests in a one-sample context?

**Signed rank**

Is there a form of the signed rank test where the difference $A-B$ for each subject is not a difference in repeated measures, but rather a difference between a single measure $A$ (my meaning of *one-sample*) and a constant value $C$? For example:

```
ID      A      C      A–C    Rank(A–C)   + Rank   – Rank
1       13     8        5      10.5        10.5    
2       14     8        6      12          12     
3        1     8       –7       1                   –1
.        .     8        .       .           .
N        2     8       –5      10.5                –10.5
```

For (above $C=8$)
$\text{H}_{0}$: The paired rank differences are symmetrically distributed about
$C$.
$\text{H}_{\text{A}}$: The paired rank differences are either not symmetrically distributed, not centered on $C$, or both.

***Aside:*** Yes, I know that the signed rank test (like the paired $t$ test) *is* a kind of/application of the one-sample approach where $C=0$. I am looking for the more general one-sample test.

**Rank sum**

Is there a form of the rank sum test where the ranks are given for a single sample and (with at least $n$ ties) for a constant value $C$? For example (for sample size of $A$ = 9):

```
ID      A      C      Rank(A)   Rank (C)
1       10     5        14          8    
2        3     5         3          8     
3       28     5        18          8
4        1     5         2          8
5        7     5        13          8
6       13     5        16          8
7       16     5        17          8
8        0     5         1          8
9       11     5        15          8
```

For (above $C=5$)
 
$\text{H}_{0}\text{: }P(A > C) = 0.5$, with
$\text{H}_{\text{A}}\text{: }P(A > C) \ne 0.5$

I keep catching elusive references to one-sample applications like these in the lit, but can't seem to find a solid citation for either or both these kinds of applications.

**Are there applications of the signed rank and rank sum tests along these lines?**

**Are there seminal citations supporting applications of the signed rank and rank sum tests along these lines?**